# UPNP problems in ADSL Modem and an Access Point

Tags: router, port-forwarding, adsl, upnp, wireless-access-point

I'm using Windows 7.
I'm using a ADSL Modem provided by my ISP to connect to the Internet. I'm using a TP-Link Access Point (WR941ND) to connect to the ADSL Modem and then I connect my computer to the Access Point.

Internet <-> ADSL Modem <-> Access Point <-> Computer

My problem is this: I want to use UPNP to open ports to the Internet. My applications says the ports are open, I can see that in Access Point (WR941ND) acknowledges the request to open the ports and says they are open. But when I try to connect with the application through UPNP the connection is refused.

I made sure that I have a connection to the Internet. In every other way the connection is good.
I made sure that UPNP is enable in both the ADSL Modem and the Access Point.
As far I can understand the ports are open up to the Access Point but not beyond that.

This means that the problem is in the ADSL Modem.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same thing, but I read somewhere using Multi-NAT does mess up port forwarding. It was suggested to use bridged mode between ADSL modem and Wireless router. I tried my way around but couldn't get it connected that way